# mysqli query with 50% within parameter and other half random

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

So , I'm struggling here with a question:

Is it possible to make a query in my sql similar to this:

- at least 20% of the results from category A
- at least 15% of the results from category B
- at least 10% of the results from category C
- at least 10% of the results from category D

and the other 50% random ( category a,b,c,d,e,f,g, and so on ) ?

I've tried to search a while but didn't find a good answer so I'm hoping that any one here can give a good hint.

Thanks in advance!!

Before anyone asks and give me a thumbs down, I'm asking this so I can profile my website visitors. Its not at all a random question.

PS: the php tag is because sometimes I use php functions to solve this kind of problems and the website is php based

Comment: And where is php in the question? If you use it it would be easy to acheive this with limit clause and few queries.

Comment: the website is php and mysql based! 
Sometimes I solve my sql problems using php functions. The info might help in any case! I'll update so everyone knows this :D

Comment: Could probably involve counting the number of records per category first, and then string a couple of SELECT statements selecting a limited number out of each category based on those counts together via UNION …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly are you trying to do but I think you can solve your problem with different approach , but anyway i thought about your question and the only idea came in my mind is the following :

*supposing your have a total 5000 rows and you want to SELECT only 50 rows of them where these 50 rows distributing according to your percentage  .

```
$limit = 50;
$cat_a_per = $limit *0.2; // 20% of the results
$cat_b_per = $limit *0.1; // 10% instead of yours 15% because 15% is incorrect ( try to sum percentages up :) ) 
$cat_c_per = $limit *0.1; // 10% of the results
$cat_d_per = $limit *0.1; // 10% of the results

$rest_per =  $limit*0.5; // the rest 50%

 // Now create a 5 mysql queries like the following :
"Select * From my_table where cat='A' limit $cat_a_per" ..
"Select * From my_table where cat='B' limit $cat_b_per" ..
"Select * From my_table where cat='C' limit $cat_c_per" ..
"Select * From my_table where cat='D' limit $cat_d_per" ..
 "Select * From my_table  limit $rest_per" ..
```

Now sum up the results in one array or use UNION and you are good to go ...